# Возвращение двух переменных из метода

Tags: c#, методы

Помогите самовару.
Есть два метода, которые по отдельности возвращают координаты х и у соотвественно.
Как сделать так, чтобы один метод возвращал сразу две переменные, чтобы не разбивать на два метода?
Код прилагается:

```
        public double FindCrossCordX()
        {
            x = (b2 - b1) / (a1 - a2);
            return x;
        }

        public double FindCrossCordY()
        {
            y = a1 * x + b1;
            return y;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если ваши `x` и `y` объявлены с модификатором static до вызова метода, а так же известны значения переменных `a1, a2, b1, b2`, то:

```
public void PerformCalculate()
{
  x = (b2 - b1) / (a1 - a2);
  y = a1 * x + b1;
}
```

если `x` и `y` не объявлены, то:

```
public void PerformCalculate(out double x, out double y)
{
      x = (b2 - b1) / (a1 - a2);
      y = a1 * x + b1;
}
```

Использование метода, в случае нестатичных `x` и `y`:

```
double x, y = 0.0;
PerformCalculate(out x, out y);
```

Так же вы можете использовать кортежи (tuples):

```
public (double x, double y) GetCrosses()
{
   double get_x = (b2 - b1) / (a1 - a2);
   double get_y = a1 * x + b1;
   var result = (x:get_x, y: get_y);
   return result;
}
```

Применение:

```
var tuple = GetCrosses();
 Console.WriteLine(tuple.x);
 Console.WriteLine(tuple.y);
```

Или сформировать собственный класс для результата.

Comment: По кортежам у Майков есть большая статья, там все полностью расписано: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tuples